# App is freezing on startup when using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.Headers.Add(@"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(Config.MessagingURL), "POST", json);
    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
}
```

Above lines are rendering application not responsive for few seconds. Also the main form is drawn partially. After few seconds all is fine again. I thought request and response are happening in separate thread, which doesn't look to be a case, unless I am doing something wrong. Same result is when I put this code in OnLoad handler of main form.

Question is how to prevent freezing on startup?

Comment: Set your `UploadStringCompleted` event before the async call.

Comment: It's not done in a separate thread, *it's done without the use of any thread at all.*  IO is inherently, by it's very nature, asynchronous, and is not dependent on a thread at all to do its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen similar issues of UI hang caused by the [`WebClient.Proxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx) property:

> The Proxy property identifies the IWebProxy instance that communicates
>   with remote servers on behalf of this WebClient object. The proxy is
>   set by the system using configuration files and the Internet Explorer
>   Local Area Network settings.

Try explicitly setting it to `null` before making the request (i am assuming you are not making this request behind a proxy):

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Proxy = null;

    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.Headers.Add(@"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
    webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(Config.MessagingURL), "POST", json);
}
```

Comment: Wow, it seems like this one solved the issue. I will test a little more though!

Comment: I was lucky this particular task doesn't require proxy. What if I need to use proxy?

Comment: Try looking at [`HttpClient` nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) for .NET 4.0. I haven't encountered anything similar there.

Comment: I just guess that alternatively I can set proxy params from my own application. Querying IE properties might be the case for blocking operations. Prevent this query may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `Task.Factory.StartNew` which is thread safe

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
     webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     webClient.Headers.Add(@"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
     webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { webClient.UploadDataAsync(new Uri("your uri"),"POST",json); });
}
```

Comment: You dont need an extra `ThreadPool` thread to do IO bound work.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov got it.. UploadDataAsync will retun the control flow, but he is still facing the issue. Why it is?